# $.post json request doesn't return any result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, .post

Well, another try:

this is all the jquery code i'm using maybe i made something wrong in the code before $.post(); i call the following function with the onclick of the same form...

```
function setLogin()
{

$('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
            //passing form field to vars
    var formUsername=$("#login-form #username").val();
    var formPassword=$("#login-form #password").val();
            //checks on fields lenght
    if((formUsername.length<6))
    {
        $("#ajax-output").html("<div class='error'>Attenzione username troppo breve!</div>");
    }
    else if((formPassword.length<6))
    {
        $("#ajax-output").html("<div class='error'>Attenzione password troppo breve!</div>");
    }
    else
    {
        $.post(
                            //the url
            '?module=login',

                            //data got from login form
            {
                "username": formUsername,
                "password": formPassword,
            },
            //response
            function(data){
                $("#ajax-output").html(data.reply)
            },
            //type
            "json"

        );
    }
});
}
```

i tried with only this code in php file and it still doesn't return anything...

```
function Login()
{
    //just to try
echo json_encode(array('reply'=>'foo'));
}
```

it still doesn't work...

Comment: Why so many @ before ? Error shouldn't happen and slow down the server.

Comment: when json is set it doesnt return any reply (data.reply)

Comment: @ are not the problem, php code works good, it was tested a lot of times... it doesn't work only with json set in $.post

Comment: Are you calling the function `Login`? What does accessing it manually show? Are there any errors in the console or in your webserver's log?

Comment: Are you sure `checkLogin()` is returning `false`? You don't have anything `echo`ing if it isn't.

Comment: I assume `checkLogin()` is returning false in your PHP, as there is no path for returning anything in this case.

Comment: @AntonioCiccia I understand but it shouldn't be there in first place.

Comment: Your condition `if(!checkLogin())`, what if checkLogin() return true? No else...
Maybe this is why you don't get any results

Comment: Guys, login function works good. CheckLogin return true if login is set.

if i call the same php page without "json" in $.post() it returns all the html code returned by php and not just the echo after every if or else... so i think the problem is json...

Comment: Can you try adding an `else{ echo json_encode(array('reply'=>'foo')); }` in there to humor us?

Comment: checklogin() isn't the problem. It returns true if login is set. and i'm working without any login session set.

Comment: So in that case - checkLogin() return true so the code in this condition will not be executed (with all the json results). What will happen if you add an ELSE to this condition with the code `echo json_encode(array("reply"=>"success"));`?

Comment: posted all jquery code, maybe this can help a bit...

Comment: Why are you using a function to create a bind ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the post is being run in the first place?

Use [Firebug!](http://getfirebug.com/) (or chrome's built-in developer tools)

You can use firebug to pick apart every bit of a web page.

It has a "net" tab that shows every request that is made by the browser, including AJAX requests, and their results, headers and contents.

Use it to see if your requests is really being made, and what the result is.  Then take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're setting a header for the content type when responding - the browser may not attempt to use the JSON if it doesn't know it's receiving JSON.

```
function Login()
{
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('reply'=>'foo'));
}
```